# Real solutions to equation set

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to find all real solutions to the following set of equations:
$$\begin{align*}
b(a-c)-ad&=0\\
2ab+cb+ad-2cd&=0
\end{align*}$$

My algebra is a bit rusty, and I really have no idea where to begin (aside from maybe a long sequence of 'brute force' by substitution). I would appreciate help with this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have two equations in four unknowns, and thus you have an underdetermined system.

Comment: P.S. The [tag:diophantine-equations] tag is intended for equations that require **integer** solutions.

Comment: J.M. thank you. I'm aware this has infinite solutions, and I am looking for answers of the form: a=0,b=0,c!=0,d!=0, and the such.

Comment: I've asked Wolfram Alpha to solve this system: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+ba-bc-ad%3D0%3B+2ab%2Bcb%2Bad-2d*c%3D0. This is the kind of answer I'm looking for, but I have no idea how it arrived at this answer.

Comment: Okay... if you know that $a$ and $b$ are zero, why not substitute those in into your equations? Did you really need integer solutions (in which case I'll restore the former tag) or are you allowing real solutions?

Comment: @J.M. It's a homogeneous system, so there are "effectively" only 3 variables :). (Actually, I am able to solve the equation to get a sensible-looking answer.)

Comment: J.M.: I did not need integer solutions; that's a result of me not understanding what a diophantine equation is. Sorry"! About substituting: it is easy to find reals that satisfy this equation but where, for example, b!=0...

Comment: @Sri, the problem is that josh didn't say the magic words "___ in terms of ___"... do I solve for a, for c, or for what?

Comment: J.M.: My bad. I'm expecting answers of the form "variables a,b,c are 0, d is any real", which is why I didn't consider this. You can solve for a, in example.

Comment: Yes, that is a problem. One guess is to say something like: The solution set is $\{ (a, b, 5a, 2b-a^2) \,:\, a,b \in \mathbb R \}$. Of course, we would think of this as solving in terms of $a$ and $b$. And of course, ultimately, what he wants, only he can tell.

Comment: Srivatsan: that's exactly the kind of answer I am looking for, yes. Everyone: I'm sorry for so many vague details, not used to posting questions here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT Your question can be equivalently written as:
$$
\begin{align*}
3ab=2cd \tag{1}
\\ bc+ad = ab \tag{2}
\end{align*}
$$

You can eliminate $d$ from the system by taking $a \times (1) + 2c \times (2)$, when you will get the equation:
$$
\ldots (\text{do the algebra and find the equation})
$$
Collect together all terms on one side and factor the equations. You will find that either $b = 0$ or $\ldots$. (Fill in the blank.)

- **Case 1:** Suppose $b = 0$. Can you handle this case?
- **Case 2:** Suppose $\ldots$ holds. Then in this case, $a = c = 0$. (Can you prove this? It is slightly nontrivial to show this.) In this case, what can you say about $b$ and $d$?

So, to conclude, what are all the solutions of the equation?

Comment: You are terrific, thanks a lot!

Comment: @josh, Were you able to go all the way through? In that case, if you want to, you can edit the question, showing your full work and the final solution; we can check if everything's ok.

Comment: "Do the algebra and find the equation" - I like that.

Comment: @mixedmath Thanks. :-)